# Form does only send 1 page. why? Jquery question

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

i use this table sorterplugin with jquery 
http://tablesorter.com/

now my form looks from the structure like this:

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
<table id="banot">
<tr><td>1st line 1 col</td><td> <input type="text" name="i1"/>/td></tr>
<tr><td>2nd line 1 col</td><td> <input type="text" name="i2"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>3rd line 1 col</td><td> <input type="text" name="i3"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>4th line 1 col</td><td> <input type="text" name="i4"/></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

I configured the plugin to seperate all 2 rows a new page. it works perfectly but if i send the form (in my example i have 2 pages), only the actual page's content is submitted. 
Why?

as i understand jquery does hide the other pages only clientside so why the rest of the input don't get submitted serverside with php?

If i would use tabs then it would work. Whats the difference?

thanks for sheding some light

Comment: Can you provide a working page or post your code on jsfiddle.net? I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean when you talk about a second page.  Can you clarify, or provide more code regarding how the page(s) in question relate to each other and what you're actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Or do you mean "page" as in paging on the table?  If that's the case, what is the actual table content when the form submit takes place?  If the plugin is manipulating the DOM, it may be moving your input elements out of the form element.

Comment: Sorry here is the pager demo i am using http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html . the "hidden" pages are taken some kind out of the form!? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i searched for a table paginator which only "hides"(still present!) the other pages. Lot of jquery plugins manipulate the whole dom. the problem is that then you can't use a paged form since on submit all pages/lines have to be present.

My solution was to use a plugin like this:

1. http://www.egrappler.com/jquery-pagination-plugin-smart-paginator/
   (the one i've chosen)
2. http://plugins.jquery.com/project/paginateTable
3. https://github.com/opensoft/jquery-draggable-pagination/tree/master/demo
4. http://www.frequency-decoder.com/demo/table-sort-revisited/paginate/
5. http://en.newinstance.it/2006/09/27/client-side-html-table-pagination-with-javascript/
6. http://www.canaware.com/Default.aspx?g=posts&m=3500
7. http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/11/17/jpaginate-a-fancy-jquery-pagination-plugin/
8. http://d-scribe.de/webtools/jquery-pagination/demo/demo_options.htm

you can see the difference examining the source with firebug. tablesorter does not have other content present in the table than that is on the current page.

Answer (score 0):

Well firstly your table is broken. Closing `</td>` on the first column

Comment: hi, thx. the code here is just simplified for illustration. in my example its w3c compliant and correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to keep using tablesorter, there is a solution to your problem.
I've been looking into this for hours until I finally noticed that instead of looking on [tablesorter.com](http://tablesorter.com/), the solution can be found at [mottie.github.com/tablesorter](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/)!

The two-step solution to your problem is:

1. Download Rob G/Mottie's Github fork of tablesorter (URL above).
2. Set removeRows:false where you insert the tablesorterPager.

As I understand it, this might make sorting big tables a bit slower, but it *will* fix your problem! :)